# Angularjs simple grid Table sort by last week

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a button on-click I want to **sort table with last week dates** in angularjs. If this is my **Angular view page**.

```html
<div class="form-inline has-feedback filter-header">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.$" />
      <!-- <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i> -->
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="hideFilter=!hideFilter">Advanced Search</button>
              </div>

        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" href="/#/add">Add New</a>
      </div> <!-- Grid filter ends -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
        <thead class="data-grid-header">
          <!-- table header -->
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span class="fa fa-th-large"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='title'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Title</a>
            </th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">
              <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='startDate'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Schedule Date</a>
            </th>
          </tr>

          <!-- table filter -->
          <tr ng-hide="hideFilter">
            <th><span ng-hide="hideFilter"><input type="text" ng-model="search.title"></span></th>
           </tr>      

        </thead>

        <tbody class="data-grid-data">
          <tr ng-repeat="visit in visitsList | filter: dateRange | filter: search |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
            <td>{{visit.title}}</td>
            <td>{{visit.startDate | date:medium}}
         </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

dont know how to fill *controller* to sort last week .
do help *thanks in advance*

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or JSFiddle with sample data?

Comment: well the truth is idk how to do dat convert my data to JSFiddle/Codepen..... if you the answer how to get the week... plz do help....smile...

Comment: Can you provide data in 'visitsList'? Sample data would do.

Comment: dey are jus dates you can take any ...can take any between 2weeks past somthing to get last week.....